# Valor de checkbox em campo input hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com um problema com manipulação de checkbox com jQuery.
Eu tenho varios fieldsets com checkboxs, e eu quero que quando a pessoa clique em um check o valor do check seja adicionado ao input hidden de cada fieldset.

Eu queria saber como eu pego esse value do check que foi clicado.

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
var text  = document.getElementById("text2");

$("#radios1 .check").click(function () {
    text1.value = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("checked");
    alert(text1.value);
});
```

```html
<fieldset id="radios1">
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="1"> <br />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="text1" value="1" />

</fieldset>

<fieldset id="radios2">
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="1"> <br />
<input class="check" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input type="hidden" id="text2" value="1" />
</fieldset>
```

Eu fiz um JSFIDDLE com o que eu tenho até agora: https://jsfiddle.net/ejb5mgoy/

Alguém sabe como proceder?

Comment: Será adicionado (tipo somado ?), será adicionado (tipo separado por vírgula), ou será atualizado o valor pelo último click?

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('fieldset[id^="radios"] .check').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input:hidden').val(this.value);
});
```

O seletor `fieldset[id^="radios"]` seleciona todos os fieldset cujo ID começa com `radios`.

Depois, dentro da função podes usar o `.closest()` para ir ao `fieldset` onde esse elemento está e depois ir procurar esse `input` escondido com `.find()`.

Desta maneira não inporta em os IDs dos elementos, funciona com *N* pedaços iguais.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qcnq1dyz/

Comment: Boa! Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Cara, eu tive um problema. Quando eu coloco em uma tabela, ele não funciona.

Comment: @LuanGabriel qual é o elemento que contem ambos o checkbox e o input:hidden?

Comment: @LuanGabriel mostra o novo HTML que tens para poder ajudar-te a usar a minha resposta

Comment: Ta aqui o que eu tenho agora, https://jsfiddle.net/qcnq1dyz/1/, tirando ta table o seu codigo funciona 100%. Mas dentro não consigo acessar. Sou meio leigo em JS, sofrimento.

Comment: @LuanGabriel esse HTML é inválido. Estás a misturar `fieldset` no meio da estrutura de `table`. Qual é a ideia de usares `fieldset`? não podes usar uma classe na `tr`  por exemplo? o HTML vem de onde?